# Overflow container stops access to slider touch/swipe

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hope you can help. I'm a bit of a newb and despite research have not found a way of fixing my issue. I have a transparent navigation bar sitting over the top of a slider that has touch swipe functionality as well as arrow nav buttons to click next/previous. Directly under the transparent nav is a tab that shows/hides text content (using jquery). See the test link below.

The problem is that in order for the show/hide to disappear behind the nav, it needs to sit in a div container that has overflow:hidden. This is the container coloured red in my test below. Unfortunately on mobile, this container covers most of the page and prevents the touch swipe functionality over most of the page. If anyone can offer any suggestions on whether it's possible to collapse the red containing div when you close the show/hide, I'd be very grateful.

http://the3rdobject.com/test/index.html

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a callback. On that callback you can show/hide the div that bothers you.

More details here: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/.

What interest you is this part:

```
 $( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
     $( "#book" ).toggle( "slow", function() {
        // Animation complete.
     });
 });
```

In your case you probably want to do something like this:

```
 $( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
     $( "#book" ).toggle( "slow", function() {
        $("#botheringDivId").hide();
     });
 });
```

You may need to adapt it a bit to fit your needs but that should be easy.

Comment: I'm not finding this easy at all... Trying many variations of what you've suggested just hides the whole panel as it's the outer container that is the troublesome thing here.... as it is the parent, trying to hide it in any shape way or form just hides the children and everything disappears... I am a newb with jquery but tbh - easy stuff I normally tend to work out quite quickly... this one is a struggle! Any ideas?